# Pferforming a segue from an empty ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, segue, viewcontroller

I have an empty screen (since I create all the elements in it programmatically) and I would like to segue to a different screen. Do you know how to do that? I can't connect the segue to the empty view controller (at least not with ctrl-drag).

Another thing I'd like to do is to have four buttons where all of them segue to the same screen, but different information is passed, depending on which button the user pressed. If I'd be able to connect the segue to the view controller and call it manually (catch the touchupinside event) this should work as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use `pushViewController:animated:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ctrl-drag from the viewController icon in the top bar to the destination viewController (see the screenshot). Then give this segue an identifier to perform it from code.

[image]